# Is there a way to notify Azure Data Factory when a file is uploaded to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, notifications, event-handling, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

We have a requirement to copy files from S3 to ADLS. We will be receiving the files in the S3 bucket using an orchestrator job. Is it a way to notify ADF when the file is placed in the S3 bucket, so that it can copy to ADLS?

Comment: Hi @savitha george, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: do you have any other concerns? Please feel free to let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory can't do that directly. It don't support listen the Amazon S3, and only support [event trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#event-based-trigger) for blob storage.

If you want to do that, you need use other service, Logic app has the trigger for Amazon S3: [when an S3 object is uploaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/amazons3/#when-an-s3-object-is-updated):
[image]

Here's the workaround:

1. Create a Data Factory with parameter to copy the file from S3 to
   ADLS
2. Logic app with trigger **when an S3 object is uploaded** to get the
   file name in S3
3. Add an action [Create a pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#create-a-pipeline-run) to run the Data factory pipeline and pass the trigger output filename as the parameter.

Logic app overview:
[image]

HTH.